# SQL Import Wizard to Access Database with password error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-import-wizard

I have an accdb access database (2007-2016 version), I am trying to set up a SSIS package to import data to SQL Server via the SQL Import wizard. It all works fine if the access database doesn't have a password but when encrypting the accdb file it doesn't work. I have tried to set the password in the import process but it doesn't recognise it. Any help?

Comment: Unless I recall incorrectly, the import wizard, and SSDT, doesn't support passworded files (password to read that is; if it's password to edit, but can be accessed read-only without one then it isn't an issue (or at least for Excel)). You'll need to remove the password to be able to access it.

Comment: I actually found out the problem, it had an older engine installed than what SQL Server was. I updated the driver and it now imports from a password protected access database